# How to call a user defined function from c++ using ADO

Tags: c++, sql-server-2008, ado

I'm trying to call a user defined function on my microsoft SQL server from a console application written in c++. I use ADO for the whole thing.

My function looks like this (and it works when i use it from within the management studio)

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[funcHowOftenDidHeWin] 
(
    @playername as varchar(15)
    @percentWon float OUTPUT
)
RETURNS float
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @wintimes float
    DECLARE @participated float
    DECLARE @percentWon float

    SELECT @wintimes = COUNT(DidWin)
    FROM PPLP0p02
    WHERE DidWin = 1 AND Playername=@playername

    SELECT @participated = COUNT(DidWin)
    FROM PPLP0p02
    WHERE Playername = @playername

    IF @wintimes >0
        SET @percentWon = @wintimes  / @participated  *100
    IF @wintimes = 0
        SET @percentWon = 0

    RETURN @percentWon
END
GO
```

From my program I try to call it as follows:

```
USEADO::_ConnectionPtr connection;                              
USEADO::_RecordsetPtr recordset;                                //create a "

    if(FAILED(hr = CoInitialize(NULL)))                         //
    {   return hr;} 

   if(FAILED(hr = connection.CreateInstance(__uuidof(USEADO::Connection))))
    {  return hr;}

   if(FAILED(hr = recordset.CreateInstance(__uuidof(USEADO::Recordset))))
    {   return hr;}

connection->CursorLocation = USEADO::adUseServer; 


    try
   { 
    connection->Open(L"Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=Test;Initial  Catalog=Haufen;Data Source=Wolle\\SQLEXPRESS", L"Test", L"Test", USEADO::adConnectUnspecified);    
   }
    catch(...)  {std::cout << "!!! connection->Open(ConnectionString   FAILED !!!" << std::endl;        }



//This works
recordset->Open("SELECT playername FROM Summary WHERE playersatbegin=5",connection.GetInterfacePtr(),adOpenDynamic,adLockOptimistic,adCmdText);


//This not
recordset->Open("SELECT dbo.funcHowOftenDidHeWin('Lumpi') ",connection.GetInterfacePtr(),adOpenDynamic,adLockOptimistic,adCmdText);
```

Well, it does not work. The debugger ends in masado15.tli in line 1580 and VS shows a window with the error:  Unhandled exception at 0x7c812afb in 35h.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x0012c3f8.

I'm not sure if the syntax is correct, i wonder how the server is supposed to know from which table I want the results....

Any help out there ?  Thanks

Lumpi

Comment: Do you get an error?  If so...paste it in here.

Comment: The error is: Unhandled exception at 0x7c812afb in 35h.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x0012c3f8..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite the function as a stored procedure.  The FLOAT can be returned either as a RETURN value or as an OUT parameter.

Comment: I tried it with a stored procedure, does not work either. I think the problem is somewhere else. e.g Is it correct to use recordset->open ? Do I have to do (initialize) something before I try it??

Comment: I know it should work with the stored procedure if the current user has been granted execute permission on the proc. You can either rewrite as a SP or wrap the function in SP.  Post your code where you attempt to invoke the stored proc, along with any errors.

Comment: Your function does not return a recordset. It returns a scalar.

Comment: I thought that it could be something like that.. Ok total newbee question: What kind of data instead of recordset do I have to use? I've rewritten it as a sp, does not work, I'll check the permissions. Thanks